# Finding how many days left per user per year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, difference

I have a table that tracks **leave days** for each user:

```
    ID   |  Start      |       End     |    IDUser
     1   | 02-02-2020  |   03-02-2020  |       2
     2   | 01-02-2020  |   21-02-2020  |       2
```

*IDUser connects to the Users Table, that has IDUser and Username columns*

I have a **view / exhibition / query** that shows previous mentioned columns data **PLUS a column named UsedDays that counts how many leave days were used**:

```
DATEDIFF(DAY, dbo.leavedays.start, dbo.leavedays.[end]) + 1
```

This is what I have now:

```
    Start      |       End     |  IDUser  | UsedDays
  02-02-2020   |   03-02-2020  |     2    |     1     
  01-02-2020   |   21-02-2020  |     1    |     20
```

Each user has a total available number of days per year so I would like to have a column that subtracts from those total possible days of each user, and show how many are left.

Example:

*John (IDUser = 2) has 30 days available this year and he already used 1, so there are 29 left*

```
    Start      |       End     |  IDUser  | TotalDaysYear | UsedDays | LeftDays
  02-02-2020   |   03-02-2020  |     2    |      30       |     1    |    29
  01-02-2020   |   21-02-2020  |     1    |      20       |     20   |     0
```

I believe I have to create a table for TotalDaysYear, probably with:

```
    ID   |  Year   |  TotalDaysYear | IDUser
     1   |  2020   |       30       |    2
     2   |  2020   |       20       |    1
```

*IDUser connects to the Users Table, that has IDUser and Username columns*

But I'm having trouble finding the logic for the relationship and how to find the result that I want, since it depends also on the year (available days may change per yer, per user).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using SQL Server, this should work:

```
SELECT 
    ld.start,
    ld.[end],
    ld.IDUser,
    ldy.TotalDaysYear,
    SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, ld.start, ld.[end])+1) OVER (PARTITION BY ld.IDUser, YEAR(ld.start) ORDER BY ld.start) as UsedDays,
    ldy.TotalDaysYear -  SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, ld.start, ld.[end])+1) OVER (PARTITION BY ld.IDUser, YEAR(ld.start) ORDER BY ld.start) as LeftDays
FROM leavedays ld
LEFT JOIN leavedaysperyear ldy
    ON YEAR(ld.start) = ldy.Year AND ld.IDUser = ldy.IDUser
```

Basic idea is to have a running total of Used Days per user, per year and then subtract it to total available days for that user, during that same year.

Here's a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6c9dc2/1)

NB. The example provided doesn't handle leave periods across years